# Saving a varible string to a file is not working

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a save which Saves data From a text edit to a file. The edit var is not seeming to put any data to the file though. The file ends up with 0 bytes inside of it.

```
Gui, Add, Tab, x2 y-1 w250 h20 , Main|Code
Gui, Font, S9 CGreen, Verdana
Gui, Tab, Code
Gui, Add, Edit, x2 y39 w1410 h630 vMencode , Edit
Gui, Font, S13 CRed, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, x1452 y39 w100 h30 +BackgroundTrans, Code Snips
Gui, Font, , 
Gui, Add, Button, x1422 y79 w60 h30 , Create Gui
Gui, Add, Button, x1512 y79 w60 h30 , Add Button
Gui, Add, Button, x1422 y119 w60 h30 , Add Pic
Gui, Add, Button, x1512 y119 w60 h30 , New Sec
Gui, Tab, Main
Gui, Add, Button, x2 y429 w100 h30 , Start String
Gui, Add, Button, x252 y-1 w90 h20 , Test Game
Gui, Tab, Code
Gui, Add, Button, x2 y669 w100 h30 gAddhelp, Add helpers
Gui, Add, Button, x100 y669 w100 h30 gSave vGMVSAVE, Save File
Gui, Show, x263 y180 h758 w1593, Temrin Dev Engine
Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

Addhelp:
Gui, Tab, Code
FileRead, FileContents, Organ.gmv
GuiControl, , Mencode, %FileContents%
return


Save:
FileSelectFile, FileName, S16,, Save File, Game Managment Varibles (*.gmv)
Sleep, 2000
FileAppend, 
(
%Mencode%
), %FileName%
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So close! You're missing one crucial command in your `Save` routine:

```
Gui, Submit [, NoHide]
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Submit

Comment: In what location of the save routine should I insert the text?

Comment: As soon as you want to read the values of the Gui controls. It can be anywhere in the subroutine. Typically the first line.